# Can we adjust the size of native ad to whatever we want?

Tags: android, android-layout, resize, admob, native-ads

My Question is simple. I just want to ask can we adjust the size of any native ad whatever we want. For example we want the size of ad `80dp * 80dp`. Can we set that?
Thanks for any kind of Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, **you can't**.

**Admob** supports limited size of ad banners. 300X250, 468X60 and 728X90. These all sizes are From admob and fits all devices. 80X80 dp will not fit any ad in it, However you can use Smart Banner from admob. It has some smaller sizes, but we can not make much custom size.

Link: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner#smart_banners

Comment: can we add the native ads into our app now a days? bcz admob  express has been discontinued and native advanced is in beta yet.